# Declare attribute of type that extends 2 different interfaces

Tags: java, generics, types, attributes, covariance

I would like to declare attribute that holds instance of class that implements 2 different interfaces. I have tried this syntax:

```
private <? extends Interface1 & Interface2> name;
```

and this:

```
private <T extends Interface1 & Interface2> T name;
```

None of those work. Is it possible? What's the syntax? I'm trying to avoid declaring another interface that inherits from both `Interface1` and `Interface2`.

---

### Edit:

The class containing this attribute should not have any type arguments. That is nothing like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Interface1 & Interface2>{
    private T name;
    ...
}
```

It would not make any sense for those using the class. It is not expected neither logical not possible for that class to be generic.

Comment: is this an instance variable declaration ??

Comment: drasto, you cannot declare the type argument at instance variable level, you can only use it after you declared in the class declarations as in the below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **variable** cannot be generic.

```
private <T> T var;
```

is not possible - at which point is `T` defined? When accessing `var`, I cannot make much assumptions on what I used at assignment time.

Java allows generics on **classes** and on **methods**. So you can have

```
private <T implements Cloneable & Serializable> void setVar(T val);
```

and you can have a class-wide type `T`.

But always remember that **in the end, it is implemented by type erasure**. You can always emulate more complex logic using getters, setters and casts. When done properly, it will give you just as much type safety.

The simplest way to obtain a variable with the type safety you want is to just use two variables, and a setter to keep them in sync.

```
private Serializable vars;
private Cloneable vars;
```

will of course give you a good type safety. But yes, it needs 4 bytes of additional memory, and a setter.

Here's the casting approach you asked:

```
private Object internal_var;

// Implementation notice: do not remove this generic.
// Due to a Java limitation, we *do* want these two constraints!
public <T extends Serializable & Cloneable> void setVar(T val) {
    internal_var = val;
}

public Serializable getSerializable() {
    return (Serializable) internal_var; // Type checked in setter!
}

public Cloneable getCloneable() {
    return (Cloneable) internal_var; // Type checked in setter!
}

// This is the way to use it in a generic getter:
public <T extends Serializable & Cloneable> T getVar(Class<? super T> cls) {
    return (T) cls.cast(val);
}
```

Note that in order to use `T` in the getter, we *do* need to have a parameter involving T.
Assuming we know a class `Example implements Serializable, Cloneable`, we can then use

```
// This actually ensures we get an instance of `Example` out:
Example e = instance.getVar(Example.class);
```

Comment: add "at which point is T defined": At runtime only... I thought it might be possible because it is in some other languages.
+1 Your last topic is of hight interest to me. Can you show me example of how to emulate that more complex logic using getter, setters and casts keeping type safety?

Comment: At runtime, `T` is `Object`. Type erasure.

Comment: Sorry, but that solution with 2 variables is the worst thing I could do. That is the most obvious solution that I'm trying to avoid. Attribute duplication is the least robust think to do. I have to take in mind that my class is likely to be modified by different people in future and some of them might not use setter and introduce an ugly bug. I'll rather create that interface.

Comment: Well, the interace may require you to modify a lot of classes. Alternatively, you can still do the cast.

Comment: See elaborated examples for the cast stuff. Attribute duplication works fine **if you document the code well**. Most of the time people break things, it is on code that doesn't have comments telling them what not to do and why.

Answer (score 4):

That needs to go in the class declaration, such as:

```
public class TestG<T extends Cloneable & Serializable> {
    private T name;
}
```

One alternative is to set it in a method (but not a variable)

```
public class TestG {
    public <T extends Cloneable & Serializable> void  method(T parameter) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare that type parameter in your `class declaration`, or `method declaration`, if that is a `local variable`, and use that type instead: -

```
public class Demo<T extends Interface1 & Interface2> {
    private T t;
}
```

or: -

```
public class Demo {
    public <S extends Interface1 & Interface2> void demo(S param1) {
        S param;
    }
}
```

Comment: (before your edit)I don't want to do that. Neither I can. Please see my edit.

Comment: @drasto.. You cannot use `Type Parameter` for instance variables in a non-generic class. That's not possible. Only generic class can have a `generic type` variables.

Comment: @drasto.. Just think, if you were allowed to use `generic type` instance variables in a non-generic class, then how would you define, what that type is?

Comment: @drasto.. Though you can use it in a `method`. So, you can use the `2nd type`, where your variable will be a local one.

Comment: it is not local variable. It really is an attribute. Looks like I'll have to create the third interface for this one...
Add " Just think, if you were allowed to use generic type instance variables in a non-generic class, then how would you define, what that type is?": Actually what I wanted was perhaps avoid creating another interface by creating "virtual interface" in runtime. Seems like not possible. It would be nice Java language feature though...

Comment: @drasto.. Even that would not work, if your class is not generic. You have to have a generic class to declare a generic type variables.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want a generic class which implements both the inetrfaces. 
declare a generic type argument in your class definition and make it as an instace variable type.

```
public class Implementor<T extends Interface1<T> & Interface2<T>>  {
    private T t;

}
```

**EDIT:**

you cannot declare a type argument at instance variable declaration like

```
 private <T extends I1 &I2> T t; //this cant be achieved.
```

at method level though is possible.

```
public <T extends I1 & I2> void method(T t){

  }
```